# Native application building for android

Tags: android, android-ndk

What headers and other source should I use for building for android? I can build simple app with ndk toolchain, but when I try to build for example library libsepol, it tells that it haven't got some headers, stdio_ext.h in my example. I found this header in android's libc sources, but copying it or changing all headers gives more errors, meaning these headers are not compatable. So where I should take all headers and sources for building applications?

Comment: Are you building an Android app or building an Android ROM?

Comment: just application, I'm trying to build that library now.

Comment: From what I can tell `libsepol` is for SELinux policies. I think that would be out of scope for a regular Android app. To learn more about Android's security model see: http://source.android.com/security/index.html

Comment: Yes, it's so, I know that, that's why I build that lib, but what do you mean? I think it's completely possible to build libsepol for android. Why do you think it isn't?